# Jumping to return null

Tags: java, android

I have only ever seen something like this once before when I accidentally tried to debug in release mode, but that isn't the case here. To my question. I have this block of code in an android app:

```
if (leftRight[0] != null && leftRight[1] != null) {
    Log.d("", "test");
    return leftRight;
} else {
    Log.e("", "test134");
    return null;
}
```

When debugging, the if statement is true and it executes the first Log.d(). However, when stepping to the next line it jumps straight to the return null which I don't understand how that is possible since it is in the else rather than the if. The second Log.d() is skipped over also.

Hopefully I am just missing some small thing, but I am completely baffled as to what is going on. Anything to point me in the right direction is appreciated.

**EDIT**
If it matters, leftRight is a Point[] containing two Points.

Comment: what your function is actually returns? is it value of leftRight or null?

Comment: This is usually just a matter of the running program not being the same as the one you see (e.g., because you made changes to the program without compiling it again).

Comment: Thanks for the response guys! @user902383 it returns the correct values. Very strange. If you submit this in the form of an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function returns correct value, there is big chance there are some issues with debugger. Mismatch between lines might happened in example when your code was modified after you build it. I suggest you to clean your workspace, rebuild it and try again.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you are right, it should not happen. However, consider this code:

```
Log.d("", "test");
if (leftRight[0] != null && leftRight[1] != null) {
    return leftRight;
} else {
    return null;
}
```

It has the same effect. Maybe your compiler restructures the code in this way and the debugger is just reflecting this as best as he can ...

EDIT: you can find out whether this is the case using "javap"

EDIT2: you may also try out whether the behavior changes if you change the log messages to do something different ...

Comment: Good thought, I revised the code to use a different method in the second Log but it did the same thing. However, after reading the comment from @user902383 I checked the result and this snippet is working as intended. Odd that the debugger showed it running in this way.